# OnClickListener for ListView with new Intent data from ArrayList for each onItemClick

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, onclicklistener

I'm setting up a ListView with an onClickListener for each item.  This is being setup in an AsyncTask, in the onPostExecute() function;  Each item in the listview should launch an activity that views data set up in the intent.  The data comes from an ArrayList of arbitrary length.  All items in the ListView launch only the last item from the ArrayList.

```
listViewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(RegisterActivity.this, userNames, reporNames);
              localListView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);

              for(final Object s : objects){

                      localListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                          @Override
                          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
                              final Intent localIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, ViewObjectActivity.class);
                              localIntent.putExtra("id", s.getId());
                              localIntent.putExtra("permission", s.getPermission());
                              localIntent.putExtra("lattitude", s.getLattitude());
                              localIntent.putExtra("longitude", s.getLongitude());
                              startActivityForResult(localIntent, VIEW_SIT_REP_REQUEST);
                          }
                      });                     
              }
```

listViewAdapter is pretty straight forward.  it's an extension of a BaseAdapter.

I had this working when It was buttons in a linear layout, and it was an OnTouchListener.  Don't know what I changed to break it, but working on it for 3 hours now.  Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to attach multiple `OnItemClickListeners` to the `ListView`, because a single `OnItemClickListener` will work for all items. Just use the `position` parameter to reference the right object from collection:

```
localListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
              final Intent localIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, ViewObjectActivity.class);
              localIntent.putExtra("id", objects[position].getId());
              localIntent.putExtra("permission", objects[position].getPermission());
              localIntent.putExtra("lattitude", objects[position].getLattitude());
              localIntent.putExtra("longitude", objects[position].getLongitude());
              startActivityForResult(localIntent, VIEW_SIT_REP_REQUEST);
          }
});
```

Comment: Oh!!  Let me try that.

Comment: Right on!  Thanks @Egor.  Some days I feel like I've forgot more than I learned.  Hehe

Answer (score 0):

You probably have some buttons in your listview item layout row.
Because you are writing 'I had this working when It was buttons in a linear layout'.

Buttons in row are stealing focus and onItmeClick is not working.

You can make your buttons in row layout not focusable **android.focusable="false"** and this should fix issue with onItemClick not being called